# Playing Minecraft with arrow keys as a mouse

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any way to make the arrow keys to act as a mouse?

Comment: No, you can't replace the mouse with the arrow keys; why would you want to anyway, it'd be very hard to control?

Comment: If you wanted change this on your whole computer which would make it possible then that would be a different question, and that may not belong in the section this was posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to change hitting and placing of blocks then yes,  you would hit `esc` on your key board. Go to options[image] then controls[image], ...Go to gameplay[image], click on what you want to change and press the key you want to change it to.

You can have keys act as a mouse, but it really doesn't have anything to do with Minecraft to be able to have a mouse as keys on your computer.   This link has a step by step instructions for all windows users on how to make your numeric keys work as a mouse.  http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000542.htm

Comment: The asker wants to know how to replace the **mouse** with the **arrow keys**, you cannot do this in Minecraft and you're not answering the question.

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox This is answering how to replace mouse actions with keyboard actions, which is one possible interpretation of a vague question. I think this is probably the best answer you can get without suggesting 3rd party tools for keyboard to mouse movement.

Comment: As a note if one uses the default windows MouseKeys accessability system, then the numpad will be able to click as well, so you'll only need to change the "Attack/Destroy" key if you don't want the default click key (which is keypad-5 for click and keypad-0 for hold (keypad-. for release) IIRC)